# Not a conda environment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda

i am trying to launch conda from the terminal on windows.

From the relevant folder ('Desktop > Course'), i installed the jupyter notebook ('pip install jupyter notebook') and 'nb_conda' ('conda install nb_conda'). Then i open the jupyter notebook by entering the command 'jupyter notebook'.

So far so good.

But when i go in the 'Conda' tab on the jupyter notebook, after 2 second i get the message ''EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: Desktop > Course'

Why is that ?

Comment: _i am trying to launch conda from the terminal on windows._ The rest of the post appears to be about jupyter notebooks, not launching Conda. Can you clarify your question? If you're using Conda, why install jupyter through pip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions-

1 - (***not personally recommended***) This is because you have probably not created the conda environment. For creating a new environment with all the dependencies look here- https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda

2 - (***personally recommended***) Install the complete anaconda distribution from here- https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda (check for windows and download for the python of your choice). After that either you can create a virtual environment and launch your jupyter from there or directly launch from the base environment. This will take care of all the dependencies and also it will help in all your future endeavors.

While following 2nd suggestion, make sure to uninstall all your previous python installations. Give it a fresh installation and while installation make sure to tick the box where it asks for adding conda to the system path.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 7):

It worked for me as well on Windows 10.

Some time ago, I installed Python. Later on, I installed Anaconda to run `pandas_datareader`, etc. It didn't work. Reinstallation didn't help, either. Then I cleaned all installation of Python and Anaconda and started from scratch.

I made a fresh new installation of Anaconda:

1. Then I ran the command line as `admin`
2. I proceed:

   ```
   conda update conda
   conda update anaconda-navigator
   ```
3. I went to "Environments" in the Anaconda Navigator
4. Then clicked on "Update Index" in the middle top
5. I waited for it to finish
6. Then, I went back to "Home" and launched the Jupyter

It seems like the environment was inconsistent, at least that was the message of `conda update`.

Comment: I have the same problem. This solution works but I have to do it EVERY time I launch Anaconda. There must be a better way. Please - if anyone is aware of one, let us all know.

Answer (score 5):

Not saying this is the right answer but this worked for me:

1. I went to "Environments" in the Anaconda Navigator
2. Then clicked on "Update Index" in the middle top
3. Waited for it to finish and went back to "Home"

Was able to launch Jupyter Notebook just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the `Not a conda environment` error when re-installing conda while having the environment activated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the command prompt from anaconda. This might solve your problem