# Jupyter notebook can't find environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I follow the below tutorial to set up my Jupyter notebook environment. https://github.com/mrdbourke/pytorch-apple-silicon

It worked for me before, but today I can't open the environment using `conda activate ./env`.

The terminal show this "EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: /Users/myname/pytorch-test/env".

Do someone knows how to solve this problem? I have already tried to update conda and update anaconda-navigator. The solution mentioned in this link is not worked for me.
[Not a conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61350929/not-a-conda-environment)

P.S. Sorry for my poor English!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369030/could-not-find-conda-environment) help?

Comment: Thank for replying! I tried this solution and I think it doesn't work for me.